# Transition effect - Fade to Slide

Tags: jquery, css, slider

I'm using this slider i found:

[Lean Slider](http://dev7studios.com/lean-slider/)

I want to know if there is any possibility to change it's transition effect from FADE to SLIDE?
I have a basic knowledge in javascript/JQuery.
I tried to look for it but there is no mention to "fade" or "slide" in the code, so i don't know where to begin.

Thanks.

Comment: show your code which you have tried so far..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this slider the fade effect is given using the css `opacity` property.

I have updated the css for slide effect. See if this helps.

Used `margin` instead of `opacity`.

```
.slider-wrapper { 
    position: relative; 
    background: #fff url(images/loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    overflow: hidden; //Added this
}
.lean-slider { /* overflow: hidden; */ width: 1000%;}
.lean-slider-slide {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: margin 0.6s linear;
    -moz-transition: margin 0.6s linear;
    -ms-transition: margin 0.6s linear;
    -o-transition: margin 0.6s linear;
    transition: margin 0.6s linear;

    width: 800px;
    margin-left: -800px;
}
.lean-slider-slide.current { margin-left: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you!! it worked! but the images are not swapping smoothly...one go in and one go out not in the same time - so i get an empty background between the swaps.
i want them to be in a row...and just move aside, like a conveyor belt.
what should i do?

Comment: Not sure you can achieve this with CSS only. This will need editing the plugin. Quick suggestion find and use another plugin instead of the exsisting one.